# Unstated.js accessing container within other container

Tags: reactjs, unstated

I've just started looking into unstated and I've bumped into an issue for which I can't find an answer yet.

Suppose I have two containers:

- ContainerA
- ContainerB

What should I do if I wanted to either access ContainerB state in ContainerA or even call a method of ContainerB in ContainerA?

The only way I see so far is to call ContainerA method and pass ContainerB instance manually as a separate argument which seems extremely bad and repetitive given I may need to do the same in multiple places...

Comment: haven't worked on this, but by looking at their library, for your use case, shouldn't you subscribe container b in container a? or vice versa

Comment: As far as I understand no - you can't even reference other containers inside the one that you are trying to do that. Subscription is used to hook container into some component

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the unstated docs around dependency injection. That allows you to instantiate your containers before adding them to your provider. So you can wire together your containers any way you like. Seems legit?

```
const containerA = new ContainerA();
const containerB = new ContainerB({ containerA });

render(
  <Provider inject={[containerA, containerB]}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid :(

Comment: This is not the answer we were looking for. We expected a normal IoC kind of solution and not a manual process.

Comment: Then Unstated is probably not the React state library you're looking for. I just explained the API of Unstated, I didn't design it, not sure why the downvote ...